# Nestjs graphql playground "Server cannot be reached"

Tags: nestjs, apollo-server, graphql-playground, nestjs-graphql

I have a v9 `Nestjs`, `graphql` that works locally without any issues but when deployed on a digital ocean droplet with nginx, accessing `playground` says `Server cannot be reached`. And as such the Schema and Doc tabs on the playground don't load. However, a query or mutation request works. How can I solve this?

[image]

[image]

I applied cors as shown below but it made no difference

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: {
      credentials: true,
      origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://api.my-live-server.io'],
    },
  
  });
```

The related dependencies are:

```
    "@nestjs/apollo": "10.1.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "10.1.2",
```

Worth-noting that an issue almost similar as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69046284/apollo-server-express-playground-cannot-be-reached) on Stackoverflow and the answer pointed to a Github [issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-playground/issues/877) that doesn't have exactly the same circumstance and doesn't resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

When NODE_ENV is set to production, the boolean value of playground and introspection will be set to false.

Please make sure these values are set to true explicitly.

```js
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      playground: true,// Set this manually if NODE_ENV=production
      introspection: true,//Set this manually if NODE_ENV=production
    }),
```